# Kubernetes and settings.xml in jenkins-agents

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am configuring a Jenkins controller to start agents with kubernetes.
When a slave starts its pipeline I need him to have a maven `settings.xml` read (or copied) from the controller.
With kubernetes plugin I haven't found a way for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe Jenkins [Pipeline: Basic Steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#pipeline-basic-steps) can help you out. They offer a [stash/unstash](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-stash-code-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) step. Meaning you stash the `settings.xml` on the master node and unstash it on your slave that runs the build. I think currently stash/unstash only support sub-directories of the current pipeline workspace, but you could work around it by copying the `settings.xml` into the current workspace before stashing. The whole thing might look something like that:

```
stage('Build') {
  node('master') {
    sh 'cp /path/to/master-node-settings-xml .'
    stash includes: 'settings.xml', name: 'settingsXml'
  }

  node('slave') {
    unstash 'settingsXml'
    sh 'mv settings.xml /path/to/slave-node-settings-xml'

    # Start your build here now ..
  }
}
```

Another option would be to pre-bake the `settings.xml` into the docker image which you are using to spin up the slave in Kubernetes. Of course this would not be an optimal solution, if your `settings.xml` changes dynamically or contains any kind of sensitive data (as one should avoid putting sensitive information inside a docker image if possible).